# spring replacement framework for AOP etc

Tags: spring

Is there any "Single" Spring replacement for AOP and templates to use with

- JPA
- Hibernate
- NoSQL
- SQL
- Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions isn't very clear, but I'll take a stab. JEE6 provides most of the functionality of Spring.

JPA:
Use EJB3/JPA combined. Inject your beans with CDI. AOP your beans with CDI.

Hibernate:
Don't use Hibernate, use JPA. If you want, use Hibernate as the JPA provider, but don't code to Hibernate specifications anymore.

NoSQL:
Nothing I can think of... There may be JPA bindings for Mongo, but the NoSQL landscape is profusely fragmented.

SQL:
JDBC? Or just use JPQL from JPA because it buys you platform independence and is a bit easier to write.

Android:
RoboGuice is CDI for Android basically

Comment: JEE6 provides most of the functionality of Spring => java annotation way of doing thing is a lot uglier then even juice by google.


Hibernate: Don't use Hibernate, use JPA. If you want, use Hibernate as the JPA provider, but don't code to Hibernate specifications anymore. -- can you elaborate why?

Comment: JPA is a specification. Hibernate is an implementation. Best practices dictate you code the specification not the implementation to avoid permanently coupling yourself to a library. If a major flaw pops up in hibernate, and you've coded to JPA, you could easily 'just switch' to EclipseLink with minimal fanfare.

Comment: i guess final thing which i would ask is why should a developer DI compare to plain old POJO implementations and works etc...?

Comment: I'd love to answer your question, but I don't really understand what you asked! Can you rephrase it?

Comment: What I was asking why should a developer use DI like spring over standard plain old java is there a reason why dev use it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is something that does it all. RoboGuice comes closest, on the subject of dependency injection. If you use RoboGuice, take a look at AssistedInject and Multibinder, they're separate projects but very useful. Use RoboGuice 2.0, not 1.2.

I use OrmLite as ORM tool, it doesn't do half as much as JPA which I use in Java, but still, it saves you a lot of time, compared with writing your own dao's.